# Open a modal dialog inside a div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

AngularUI seems to target the body when it opens a modal. How can I open it inside a div?

Here is how I open a modal:

```
$scope.createEntityModal = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'partials/tsp-add_entity.jade',
        controller: 'TspAddEntityCtrl',
        size: 'lg'
    });

};
```